# WPF Listview Virtualization mode gives issues while binding

Tags: wpf, listview, mode, recycle, virtualizingstackpanel

I have created a new class (derived from listview).

This listview is part of a view, which has a viewmodel. This viewmodel has two main properties - 1)myView(ICollectionView)...and isWritable(bool).

Each listview item (row inside listview) has a control template which displays a set of controls.

The visibility of few of these controls is decided by "isWritable" property...thru FindAncestor method.

**The ISSUE is**..when we scroll this listview, some of the controls which uses "isWritable" property to enable/disable is disabled even though property has value as "True".

If I remove recycling, it works fine...I think this issue is - as it reuses old container..the binding is not happeneing with FindAncestor perfectly.

As u can see, I am using virtualization here..and item panels are recycled. So I think as we reuse the itempanel the databinding is not happening as expected using FindAncestor.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<controls:ListViewMine                                                   
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myView}"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    Template="{StaticResource myView2}"
    AllowDrop="{Binding Path=isWritable}">
    <controls:ListViewMine.View>
        <controls:GridViewMine ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn Width="110"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource templateName}"/> 
        </controls:GridViewMine>
    </controls:ListViewMine.View>
</controls:ListViewMine>
```

Comment: What is the down side to remove recycling?  Do you have performance issues with recycling off?

Comment: Then identify the issues.  You state "If I remove recycling, it works fine"

Comment: I mean to say - If I remove recycling ..i have performance issue..as this will reduce the performance by approx 46%. But If I retain recycling..i have the issue I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Try `VirtualizationMode="Standard"`.

Worked for the problem I had: *a celltemplate with a combobox and a selectedindex set. It was not rendering the selected index when scrolling.*

I don't know if you will get same improvement with your perf though.